# Deploy WSO2 Governance Registry on the same server as JBOSS?

Tags: deployment, wso2

Do you see any risks of deploying WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3 on the same Linux server as a JBOSS EAP 6.x application server instance? What about port conflicts? Do I need to make any specific configurations on either the JBOSS or the WSO2 software?

Note: I don't mean to install the WSO2 Governance *ON* the JBOSS application server instance, but only on the same operating system instance as per the instructions in [installation instructions](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Installing+on+Linux+and+Solaris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements and the performance expected.

You can check the default ports used by WSO2 Governance Registry from this [doc](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products).

If there is a port conflict, you can set a port offset in /repository/conf/carbon.xml as follows: `<Offset>1</Offset>`

You can also change the conflicting ports only by changing relevant configuration files since the port offset will affect to all ports.